# HP UFT error: Object required: 'Browsers'

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I'm trying to launch a page with Browsers.Item(btChrome).Run(datavalue) and check if the page contains a specific word string that I'm looking for. And I got an error of **Object required: 'Browsers'**. I'm confused because I was following the tutorial of https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/app-testing/web/general/examples/checking-specific-text.html. Can someone please point out where my code goes wrong?

```
Sub Test(datavalue)

  Dim browser, page, str, Obj

  Browsers.Item(btChrome).Run(datavalue) 'datavalue is an url
  Set browser = Sys.Browser("*")
  Set page = browser.Page("*")

  str = "*Dashboard*" 
  If browser.ObjectIdentifier = "chrome" Then
    Call aqObject.CheckProperty(body, "innerText", cmpContains, str, False)
  Else
    Call aqObject.CheckProperty(body, "textContent", cmpContains, str, False)
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: is it Browsers?  or Browser?  perhaps the extra 's' is a problem?

Comment: You've tagged the question with `hp-uft` and then referenced a tutorial for `TestComplete`, which is a totally different testing tool.  This code won't work in `UFT`.  Can you perhaps be clearer on what you're doing and what tools you are using?